# Paint Component seems to be causing cursor and Mouse Listener of Label to not work

Tags: java, swing

Using `LayerUI` to add labels to the upper corner of a tabbed pane.  Would like to allow these labels to display as hyperlinks, so I  set the color blue, the cursor to a hand and I added a `mouselistener`.

Howev,er when I paint the component the cursor customization and mouse listener are not not working.

sample image

[image]

Sample Application:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Cursor;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JLayer;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.plaf.LayerUI;

public class TopRightCornerLabelLayerUITest {
    public static JPanel makeUI() {
        JPanel resultPanel = new JPanel();
        resultPanel.setLayout( new BorderLayout());
        resultPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));
        JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
        tabbedPane.add("Tab 1", new JPanel());  
        tabbedPane.add("Tab 2", new JPanel());  

        resultPanel.add(new JLayer<JComponent>(tabbedPane, new TopRightCornerLabelLayerUI()), BorderLayout.CENTER);

        return resultPanel;
    }

    private static void initandShow()
    {
        JDialog dialog = new JDialog();
        dialog.getContentPane().add(makeUI());
        dialog.setSize(520, 240);
        dialog.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        dialog.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                initandShow();
            }
        });

    }
}

class TopRightCornerLabelLayerUI extends LayerUI<JComponent> {
    private JPanel rubberStamp = new JPanel();

    @Override public void paint(Graphics g, JComponent c) {
        super.paint(g, c);

        JLabel layoutHyperlink = new JLabel("<html><a href=''>File Layout and Descriptions</a></html>");
        JLabel templateHyperlink = new JLabel("<html><a href=''>Download Template</a></html>");

        layoutHyperlink.setForeground(Color.BLUE.darker());
        layoutHyperlink.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
        layoutHyperlink.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                // the user clicks on the label
                System.err.println("clicked");
            }
       });

        templateHyperlink.setForeground(Color.BLUE.darker());
        templateHyperlink.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
        templateHyperlink.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                // the user clicks on the label
                System.err.println("clicked");

            }
       });

        // Add components
        Dimension templateDimension = templateHyperlink.getPreferredSize();
        int x = c.getWidth() - templateDimension.width - 5;
        SwingUtilities.paintComponent(g, templateHyperlink, rubberStamp, x, 2, templateDimension.width , templateDimension.height);

        Dimension layoutDimension = layoutHyperlink.getPreferredSize();
        x = c.getWidth() - layoutDimension.width - 15 - templateDimension.width;
        SwingUtilities.paintComponent(g, layoutHyperlink, rubberStamp, x, 2, layoutDimension.width, templateDimension.height);

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post a screen shot of how it's supposed to look? I don't understand where the upper corner of the tabbed pane is. Also, perhaps you could post a sample application that I can copy and run.

Comment: added sample image, i will need to break this out of the larger app and build a custom app for this to be posted on here, give me some time to get that running.

Comment: @Abra here is a functioning example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was actually unaware of class `JLayer` until I read your question. I don't have a complete answer but I think it's enough to give you a push in the right direction. I was helped by the lesson in *Oracle*'s Java tutorial: [How to Decorate Components with the JLayer Class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/jlayer.html). That lesson has a section entitled *Responding to Events* which helped me to figure out how to partially solve your issue. Basically you are just painting the labels and not actually adding them as components and therefore they will not respond to mouse events. Since the labels can be considered part of the `JLayer` component that **is** added as a component, you can configure that `JLayer` to respond to mouse events. As stated in the tutorial lesson, you need to override some other methods in your `TopRightCornerLabelLayerUI` class. The code below contains two of those methods. Add them to your code and see if they give you the expected result.

```
public void installUI(JComponent c) {
    super.installUI(c);
    ((JLayer<?>) c).setLayerEventMask(AWTEvent.MOUSE_EVENT_MASK);
}

protected void processMouseEvent(MouseEvent e, JLayer l) {
    if (e.getID() == MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED) {
        Point pt = e.getPoint();
        if (pt.x >= xTemplateHyperlink  &&  pt.x <= (xTemplateHyperlink + widthTemplateHyperlink)) {
            System.out.println("clicked");
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT:
Forgot to mention that I added the following members to your `TopRightCornerLabelLayerUI` class...

```
private int xTemplateHyperlink;
private int yTemplateHyperlink;
private int widthTemplateHyperlink;
private int heightTemplateHyperlink;
```

And set their values in method `paint()` like so...

```
Dimension templateDimension = templateHyperlink.getPreferredSize();
xTemplateHyperlink = c.getWidth() - templateDimension.width - 5;
yTemplateHyperlink = 2;
widthTemplateHyperlink = templateDimension.width;
heightTemplateHyperlink = templateDimension.height;
```

which explains the code in method `processMouseEvent()`.